# How do i check to see if a delegate is valid?

Tags: iphone, delegates, protocols

I'm doing something like this:

```
@protocol CallbackDelegate
-(void) performCallback;
@end

@interface MyObject : NSObject {
   id<CallbackDelegate> delegate;
}

-(void)AsyncFuncCall;

@end

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<CallbackDelegate> *delegate;
```

The code that owns `MyObject` sets up a delegate to receive the callback function:

```
MyObject *myobject = [[MyOject alloc] init];
myobject.delegate = x;
```

Then in `MyObject`, as a result of an asynchronous function call I'll signal back to the delegate:

```
-(void)AsyncFuncCall {
   [delegate performCallback];
}
```

All seems to work well most of the time, except for the occasions where my delegate has been freed up as a result of valid memory cleanup. In this case, I simply want to not perform the callback

Does anyone know the best way to check to see if a delegate is valid?

I've tried all sorts of things such as:

```
if (delegate != nil) {
   ...
}
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your delegate should nil out myObject's delegate property in its dealloc to avoid this:

```
- (void) dealloc {
  if (myObject.delegate == self) myObject.delegate = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Alternatively, but not recommended, you could retain the delegate. However, this can lead to a [retain cycle](http://www.stepwise.com/Articles/Technical/HoldMe.html).

Comment: Brilliant, this looks like it should work also! 
I was previously retaining delegates to get around the problems I was having - but my code looked so messy and it didn't quite feel right.
Your solution above looks like it solves this.
Thanks again,
Nick.